# Casting dates on denodo oracle database gives a different formatting

Tags: oracle, denodo

I have a date column and I am trying to cast this into a view with a code below but the output does not match the requirement. I use denodo and oracle 18g as my database.

Column

```
  A 

1-Dec-20
12-Dec-20
11-Dec-20
```

Expected output

```
  A 

1-Dec-20
12-Dec-20
11-Dec-20
```

output I am getting after running the code below.

```
select 
to_localdate('dd-MM-yyyy', substring(replace("A", 'NULL', ''), 0, 10)) AS A from "xxtable"

   A
0020-12-01
0020-12-12
0020-12-11
```

Comment: What is the difference between values stored in the column and the output you expect? (I don't see any difference).

What is `to_localdate`? What parameters it takes (I don't know such standard Oracle function). If it was `to_date`, it would have the parameters swapped (first date string, second format mask).

Comment: This is because in denodo there is something called base view where you set everything to varchar and later you have to change it to timestamp or we cant do any calculations on top of it. The to_localdate will set it to localdate of denodo format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using yy instead of yyyy format.

```
to_localdate('dd-MM-yy', substring(replace("A", 'NULL', ''), 0, 10)) AS A from "xxtable"
```